# multiple columns from a file into a single column of lists in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm new to pandas , and need to prepare a table using pandas , imitating exact function performed by following code snippet:

```
with open(r'D:/DataScience/ml-100k/u.item') as f:
    temp=''
    for line in f:
        fields = line.rstrip('\n').split('|')
        movieId = int(fields[0])
        name = fields[1]
        geners = fields[5:25]
        geners = map(int, geners)
```

My question is how to add a geners column in pandas having same :
`geners = fields[5:25]`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you intend to accomplish -- a single genres column containing fields 5-25 concatenated? Or separate genre columns for fields 5-25?

For the latter, you can use `[pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)`:

```py
import pandas as pd

cols = ['movieId', 'name'] + ['genre_' + str(i) for i in range(5, 25)]
df = pd.read_csv(r'D:/DataScience/ml-100k/u.item', delimiter='|', names=cols)
```

For the former, you could concatenate the genres into say, a space-separated list, using:

```py
df['genres'] = df[cols[2:]].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis=1)
df.drop(cols[2:], axis=1, inplace=True) # drop the separate genre_N columns
```